# Insert two comma splitted fields as rows to temp table at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert two variables into same temp table at once but facing syntax error.

SQL Server Version used is 2012. Any possible ways of implementing this would be greatly appreciated. 
I would prefer support with Azure and Server 2012 as well.

### SOURCE DATA:

```
VARCHAR(MAX) ProgramName  AS 'SP1, SP2, SP3'
INT ProgramId AS 12,13,14
Id = Identity Column (TO be auto generated with init as 1 and seed as 1)
```

### DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Id ---- ProgramName  --- ProgramId

1  ------ SP1   ---------  12

2 ------- SP2   ---------  13

3 ------- SP3   ---------- 14
```

### TRIED CODE:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #tempTable;

CREATE TABLE #tempTable (
Id          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
ProgramName VARCHAR(50) NULL,
ProgramId   INT  NULL);

DECLARE @string varchar(max) = 'aa,dd,fe,grt,rge,lk,se';
DECLARE @new varchar(max) = '1,17,25,44,46,67,88';

DECLARE @InsertStatement varchar(max) = 'insert into 
#tempTable(ProgramName,ProgramId) 
        values ('+REPLACE(@string,',',','+REPLACE(@new,',','),(')+',(')++')';
PRINT(@InsertStatement)
EXECUTE (@InsertStatement);

SELECT * FROM #tempTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #tempTable;

CREATE TABLE #tempTable 
(
    Id          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ProgramName VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    ProgramId   INT  NULL
);

declare @t as table
(
    seqno int identity(1,1),
    ProgramId   INT  NULL
)

DECLARE @string varchar(max) = 'aa,dd,fe,grt,rge,lk,se';
DECLARE @new varchar(max) = '1,17,25,44,46,67,88';

DECLARE @sql1 varchar(max) = 'SELECT '''+REPLACE(@string,',',''' UNION ALL SELECT ''')+''''
DECLARE @sql2 varchar(max) = 'SELECT '''+REPLACE(@new,',',''' UNION ALL SELECT ''')+''''

PRINT(@sql1)
PRINT(@sql2)

insert into #tempTable(ProgramName)
exec(@sql1)

insert into @t(ProgramId)
exec(@sql2)

update a
set 
ProgramId = b.ProgramId
from #tempTable a
inner join @t b
on a.Id = b.seqno

SELECT * FROM #tempTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to use `xml` node method to split your data & insert them into `temp` table

```
;with cte as
(
    select 
          row_number() over (order by (select 1)) [rn],
          s.value('.', 'varchar(max)') [string] from
    (
       select cast('<m>'+replace(@string, ',', '</m><m>')+'</m>' as xml) [string]
    ) as a cross apply string.nodes ('/m') as string(s)
), cte1 as
(
    select 
          row_number() over (order by (select 1)) [rn],
          s.value('.', 'varchar(max)') new from
    (
       select cast('<m>'+replace(@new, ',', '</m><m>')+'</m>' as xml) [new]
    ) as a cross apply new.nodes ('/m') as string(s)
)

insert into #tempTable
select c.string, c1.new from cte c
join cte1 c1 on c1.rn = c.rn
```

Result :

```
Id  ProgramName ProgramId
1   aa         1
2   dd         17
3   fe         25
4   grt        44
5   rge        46
6   lk         67
7   se         88
```